# Python 3 printing function

Tags: python

Im trying to create a vacation calculator using keyboard input, but when I run the code I get:

```
<function trip_cost at 0x01FF3348>
```

My code is:

```
city = input("What city will you vacation at?")
days = input("How many days will you be staying there?")
def hotel_cost(days):
    return 140 * days
def plane_ride_cost(city):
    if city == "Charlotte":
        return 183
    elif city == "Tampa":
        return 220
    elif city == "Pittsburgh":
        return 222
    elif city == "Los Angeles":
        return 475
def rental_car_cost(days):
    cost = 40 * days
    return cost

def trip_cost(city, days):
    return plane_ride_cost(city) + rental_car_cost(days) +  hotel_cost(days)
print (trip_cost)
```

How can I get it to return the amount of money it will cost?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call the `trip_cost` function and print its result, you need to explicitly call it. And you also need to pass it arguments for its `city` and `days` parameters. For example:

```
print(trip_cost(city, days))
```

What you're doing is just printing the function object itself, which is legal, but not very useful.

Comment: @OceanS if this answered your question please click the tick under the arrows to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling the function, you also need to pass the two parameters:

```
print (trip_cost(city,days))
```

You will also need to make sure you define citys and days or pass the values directly to the function.

Answer (score 0):

You must call the function trip_cost with valid parameters in a print function to get it to actually print a value.